# How to get the Terminalsize with perl6/rakudo?

Tags: terminal, raku

Is there for perl6 already something to get the Terminalsize?

( for example like the perl5 "Term::ReadKey::GetTerminalSize" );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a direct method, but parsing `qx/resize/` should work on systems where the resize command is available.

Update: somewhat golfed parsing code:

```
my %h = qx/resize/.lines.grep(/\=/).map: { m/(\w+) \= (\d+) /; $/.list };
my ($y, $x) =  %h<LINES COLUMNS>;
```